# Place word index next to each word in a paragraph of text

Tags: awk, text, sed, grep

Is there any way to place the index of each word next to the word using *grep*, *sed* or *awk* (or is there any software with this functionality built in)?

For example, given this text:

```
"I love the power of Grep SED and AWK, but I am no good at using it"
```

I'd like to have this:

```
"I(1) love(2) the(3) power(4) of(5) Grep(6) SED(7) and(8) AWK,(9) but(10) I(11) am(12) no(13) good(14) at(15) using(16) it(17)"
```

**To clairfy:** `"I"` being first gets `"(1)"`, and `"it"` being last 17th word gets `"(17)"`.

Comment: Why re-post here, was answers at biostars were not clear/sufficient? https://www.biostars.org/p/449890/

Comment: To close-voters, please reconsider, post is clear enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it's not the count but the index number,

```
$ echo "I ..."  | awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) $i=$i "(" ++c ")"}1'

I(1) love(2) the(3) power(4) of(5) Grep(6) SED(7) and(8) AWK,(9) but(10) I(11) am(12) no(13) good(14) at(15) using(16) it(17)
```